# How to change fullscreen mode in settings activity android?

Tags: android, settings, fullscreen

I want to change fullscreen mode in settings and see the changes after backing from settings to main activity.
I tried:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

But I can't use it after setting content view of main activity. I tried also:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = mActivity.getWindow().getAttributes();
attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
mActivity.getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
```

but i can't use it in onResume() because my app is unable to resume activity throwing null pointer exception at the first open. 
Do you have any idea how to do fullscreen setting with changes being seen after resuming to main activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api level 11+

```
getActionBar.hide();
```

below Api level 11

`you can use getSupportActionBar.hide();` and add v7 support lib to your project

Comment: It works but I still see in main activity status bar. Is there any way to hide that to?

Comment: take a flag(boolean isNavigatedFromSettings) and use the same code there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using recent Android (4.4) you can try by adding this to onResume()

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity
            android:name=".YourSettingsActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
```